# Files are not present in SFTP directory after upload using WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I need a script that will copy files to an SFTP server using WinSCP.

- Connect
- Copy files
- If copy ok then delete local files
- Disconnect

My txt file so far :

```
# Automatically answer all prompts negatively not to stall
# the script on errors
option batch on

# Automatically answer all prompts negatively not to stall
# the script on errors
option batch on

# Disable overwrite confirmations that conflict with the previous
option confirm off

# Connect using a password
# open user:password@example.com
# Connect
open sftp://***:***@***.fr/ -hostkey=*

# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary

# Interface 1
cd /tracks
lcd "Y:\"

#Copie des données en local
get *.txt

#Envoie de données sur le serveur
put *.*

#Effacement des données
put -delete "Y:\*.txt"

# Interface 2
cd /trackm
lcd "Y:\"

#Copie des données en local
get *.tar-gz*

#Envoie de données sur le serveur
put *.*

#Effacement des données
put -delete "Y:\*.tar-gz*"

#Disconnect
#close

#Exit WinSCP
#exit
```

My bat file so far :

```
@echo off
"D:\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /log="D:\logfile.log" /ini=nul /script="D:\script_test.txt"
```

So far it doesn't upload the files, but it deletes them.

Comment: `put -delete` never deletes a file, if it has not uploaded it before. Show us a session log file (`/log=...` command-line switch).

Comment: Here it is : https:// we.tl/t-XOrwN5qD7I

Comment: If you refer to the *"Aucun fichier correspondant à '*.txt' trouvé."* -> That error message clearly comes from the `get *.txt` not from `put -delete "Y:\*.txt"` - WinSCP actually does not see any `put -delete "Y:\*.txt"` command. Make sure you execute the version of the script file that you posted in your question.

Comment: You're right, the file I executed was a little different but the only difference are that it starts with (before the option confirm off) :
    # Automatically answer all prompts negatively not to stall
    # the script on errors
    option batch on
 - This is the log I get (looks the same) : https:// we.tl/t-q3t2Gtwhef

Comment: I modified a little my previous comment and there is the new log

Comment: Still, create [mcve] and upload the resulting script for us to check, along with a matching log file.

Comment: OK, here it is https:// we.tl/t-e4rP0vUDFO. Maybe you'd need to modify Y: with C: if you don't have a Y: drive

Comment: In the script, the `put -delete` command is commented out with `#`: `#put -delete "Y:\*.txt"` - So it is ignored. => It's not the script that you have posted in your question, as I have expected.

Comment: I have just commented that line in because I didn't want the txt file to be deleted every time I tried

Comment: We cannot help you, if you do not show us a log file showing the problem.

Comment: The log file is in the zip file you downloaded at https:// we.tl/t-e4rP0vUDFO. In the folder "Outgoing_Tracks_log"

Comment: But that's for a script that has the command commented out! We need a log file for the script from your question. - And ideally for a script that does not include all the other irrelevant puts and gets => [mcve].

Comment: My question is exactly the same but the deletion part is commented out. My question is not on the deletion part, it is on the uploading file, which does not occur. In other words, I want to upload a file from local to distant and then delete the local file. But first, the upload does not work. And anyway the deletion part works fine, that's actually why I had to comment it out so that it doesn't delete my file anytime I give it a try. Is that more clear ?

Comment: That makes no sense - `put -delete` is not a command to delete files. That's a command to move local files to the server (upload and delete source files). If you comment it out, you remove also upload, not only deleting. Though it's quite probable that you actually abuse `put -delete` to delete local files, as you actually upload all files from `Y:\*.*` to the server (`lcd "Y:\"` + `put *.*`) and then you re-upload all `Y:\*.txt` files (`put -delete "Y:\*.txt"`) - which are there already! So your script is wrong (or at least pretty inefficient and confusing).

Comment: Not to mention that you you first download all .txt files from the server (`get *.txt`), only to upload them back (`put *.*`).

Comment: Anyway, both the first two puts that deal with text file upload a .txt file. What behavior were you expecting instead?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have no idea what all this means. A colleague of mine did the script and now I'm responsible for making it work because I'm a "developer". Which makes no sense at all since I don't know the language... Anyway, I just need to copy the txt files from local to distant and then IF the upload worked, delete the local files. Could you help me do this little script please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script makes a little sense.

If you want a simple script that moves all `Y:\*.txt` files to `/tracks` and all `Y:\*.tar-gz*` files to `/tracksm`, replace all your script after the `open` command with:

```
put -delete Y:\*.txt /tracks/
put -delete Y:\*.tar-gz* /trackm/
exit
```

See [documentation of `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put).

---

Though it seems that although the original script was quite ugly and inefficient, it probably did its job.

The root problem is that your server probably does some processing with the uploaded files and deletes or moves away the files after they are processed.

That's quite common behavior with servers that processes file (as opposite to storing files).
See WinSCP FAQ [Why is uploaded file not showing in a remote directory or showing with a different name?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_uploaded_file_missing)

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much ! How do I do a conditional deletion (of the local files) IF everything uploaded fine ?

Comment: `put -delete` deletes each file only after they were successfully uploaded. Or do your want to upload all files, and only after all files were uploaded, delete them all?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the simpler :) So what you wrote is enough ? I'm going to try it right away

Comment: The other option is way more difficult to implement.

Comment: Alright, then I don't need the more difficult way, thanks. However, I've just tried it out and it deletes the local file but there's nothing on the distant server. Here is the log : https:// we.tl/t-S53zRjuFKC

Comment: The log shows that the file was uploaded to `/tracks/test.txt`. If it's not there, it's hardly a fault of your script. If you upload (not move) the file to the same folder using WinSCP GUI, can you see the file there after the upload finishes?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and I see the files on the distant server... weird

Comment: So post a log file from GUI too.

Comment: I've copied 3 txt files (test, test1 and test2) and 2 tar-gz files (test and test1). Here is the log : https:// we.tl/t-EzRETrA9Uw

Comment: OK, can you add `ls /tracks` command after `put -delete Y:\*.txt /tracks/` and post a new log file from the script?

Comment: OK, so you can see that the files are there!

Comment: Oh yeah ? It's weird, I don't see them in WinSCP... Here is the screenshot : https:// we.tl/t-sGW32l25qH

Comment: And if you upload them in GUI, wait a minute and then refresh the panel, are the files still there?

Comment: Thank you very much Martin, you saved me a lot of time looking in the wrong direction. I owe you one ! All the best to you. Děkuji vám moc ;)

Comment: Done! Thanks again ;)